# SQL indexes and update timing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have a table with 50 columns and non-clustered indexes for about 10 columns (FKs). The table contains about 10 million records.

My question is: when is the index updated during the update of 10k rows in the table (update includes indexed columns)?  Does it happen after each row update or after the whole update is complete?

The problem is that the update is very long and we receive a DB connection timeout. How can I improve update time? I cannot remove indexes before update and rebuild them later, because the table is used heavily during the update too.

Comment: The indexes are updated ... when they're updated. It's possible that they're never updated, if they're non-clustered indexes and you're not changing their key or covering columns. Look at the execution plan. If your connection times out but you're confident the update will complete, perhaps you have come across a scenario where the default timeout is not suitable for you. If you can't break the update up into smaller pieces, perhaps you could try more or less aggressive locking. And so on and so forth.

Comment: Indexes boost selects and reading data at the expense of slowing down updates. If you usually do more updating than selecting, indexes might be contra-productive for you

Answer (score 3):

You should partition the table and try to use local indexes.
By partitioning you are dividing the table data so that you can operate on relevant data.

Local indexes also mean that index is partitioned as well, so speed will improve dramatically.

Have a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms190787.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, this is something new that I should investigate. Maybe this is what we need.

Answer (score 0):

We have a massive system, the main table also have a couple of million records.... At least it used to. We move data older than 6 months out to an archive table. Typically data that old is only for reporting purposes. By doing this we were able to greatly improve performance on our live system. That been said, this may not be a viable solution for you.

Comment: Unfortunately this table contains "live" data that cannot be moved to archive :(

Answer (score 0):

Are the indexes fragmented (update table and FK table)?
Type of column and does it null?
Can you live with dirty reads (nolock)?
Can you live with not checking FK contraint?

Please post the update statement?
I trust you you are checking to not update with same value.

```
update tt 
set col1 = 'newVal' 
where col1 <> 'newVal'
```

If those index are in good condition update of 10 K rows should be pretty fast.
A fill factor might help.